# Is there any way to remove csproj files from Visual Studio's "recent projects and solutions" list?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have no idea why Visual Studio lists recent csproj files that happened to be a part of a solution I was working on, but doing so causes other recent solutions to get pushed off the bottom of the list. Is there a way to get Visual Studio to only show recent solutions and leave projects out of the list?

Answer (score 1):

It is not ideal, but you can edit the list from the registry. For example, the registry key for Visual Studio 2012 is:

`HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-3957302920-3287377022-3235433541-12290\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ProjectMRUList`

You will need to restart Visual Studio to see the changes.

Comment: Thanks, was kind of looking for a way to not have to manually edit it though. It would be faster to simply locate the solution in question manually than to edit the list and hope it shows up again.